# Does anyone know what these characters are in table in a word document (docx)?

Tags: python

I am writing a routine in python, and testing it with different word documents, and it fussed about something in a document that had a table.  Here's what the table looks like with the formatting turned on.  The weird little hyphen looking characters may be the problem.  Does anyone know if python can read the character and tell me what they are, like getting an ascii or hex value for the characters are?  DOCX2TXT reads the header, body with the table and the footer. TIA.

[image]

Comment: In case you mean the dots between the words, they are spaces, and Python can read them.

Comment: I found the ord() function, but basically the size was about 128, and the new_str[0] fussed.  I think it is problem with the .... or whatever those characters are.